# Swift - Find other users running app nearby

Tags: php, ios, swift, gps

Need some help with logic. I am storing my app user's location information (lat,long) in a database on app launch (and periodically update while app is in use).

A main function of my app will be to find users nearby that are also currently running the app.

It is not sufficient to just query the database for "nearby users" within a proximity range because I need them to also be running the app.

I'm not sure how to "know" when a user has the app running versus one that used my app 5 minutes ago (logged its lat/lng) and then closed the app.

Seen similar questions (android specific), but none really touch on "active" users.

(Currently coded in Swift with PHP as my server side language)

Comment: If you log a timestamp along with the coordinates, you will be able to tell if the location is up to date and the user running the app.

Comment: Not necessarily. It'd be a good "assumption", but it's not a guarantee. I could launch the app, save my coordinates and then immediately close the app. I'd have a very recent timestamp, but would not be an active user (app up on my screen).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods in your AppDelegate to manage state and then based on state changes you can perform queries or remove a user from being eligible to be found.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.

}
```

Comment: that's great @thefreelement! It looks like I would make my DB calls for "nearby users" in the applicationDidBecomeActive function then.

Comment: Sure can, you can also manage when they are no longer eligible to be found as well.

Comment: I think that gets me on the right track now. In the "inactive" functions, I will call a PHP script that removes user from an "ActiveUser" table in the DB. In the active function, I will add them. That should give me a nice listing of Active users, which I can then use to do a lookup on my "Location" table.